# Bitcoin Cash: difference between addresses

Tags: bitcoin-cash

My BCH wallet prefixes the addresses with a **"bitcoincash:"** string and the hash itself (without the prefix) is 42 chars. Let's say I need to send some BCH to an old address (34 chars, unprefixed), will this work? If not, what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Bitcoin, i.e. BTC.  (See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) -  *"The Bitcoin stack exchange ... is not about ... any cryptocurrency or technology that is not applicable to the Bitcoin network and users of the Bitcoin currency"*    I believe these rules were altered recently and made more restrictive.

Comment: In this case, I think the bitcoin-cash tag should be remove ASAP, as it is misleading as it is.

Comment: @darksoulsong see https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/progress-tracker-of-implementing-the-scope-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If your wallet does not support this, you can use https://cashaddr.bitcoincash.org to convert the old addresses to new addresses, and send to new addresses.

Comment: Thank you, but In my case, I can't convert the old address because I have no control over it. So, do I need to convert my address to an old one in order to transfer the funds?

Comment: @darksoulsong You can take any Bitcoin Cash addres in old format, convert it, then the funds will go there safely. Both types of address are compatible with each other.

Comment: I see. But my case is the exact opposite, that is, my wallet is in the new format and I need to send funds to an address that is in the old format. In this case, I should convert my wallet address to the old format, am I right?

Sorry for sounding repetitive, but I really need to be sure on this.

Comment: The address format does not actually make any difference other than not being able to put a Bitcoin Cash new CashAddr into a Bitcoin Core textbox. Other than that, you can send/receive to/from both types of addresses. If some website/wallet doesn't accept your new address, then you can convert it to old address. Feel free to ask questions @darksoulsong .